# Hashtable is not working in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using .net framework 4.5.1 and making a simple snake game watching on youtube but its not working.

The code is as follows:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW3r3.png)

Comment: You should add a code snippet, not link to an image for this case.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
private static Hashtable keys = new Hashtable();
```

not

```
private static Hashtable_keys = new Hashtable();
```

Comment: And it also should be `using System.Collections;`

Comment: I believe he has the system.collections namespace in the using statements.

Comment: Oh, right. A habit of having using statements sorted by name.